# Chai-as-promised - expect with promise always transforms into an empty object

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, mocha.js, chai, chai-as-promised

from the documentation of chai-as-promised

> ```
> (2 + 2).should.equal(4);
>
> // becomes
> return Promise.resolve(2 + 2).should.eventually.equal(4);
>
> expect({ foo: "bar" }).to.have.property("foo");
>
> // becomes
> return expect(Promise.resolve({ foo: "bar" })).to.eventually.have.property("foo");
> ```

but if I try

```
import chai from 'chai';
import sinon from 'sinon';
import sinonChai from 'sinon-chai';
import dirtyChai from 'dirty-chai';
import chaiAsPromised from 'chai-as-promised';

chai.use(sinonChai);
chai.use(dirtyChai);
chai.use(chaiAsPromised);

//...

it.only('test', function() {
   return expect(Promise.resolve({ foo: 'bar' })).to.eventually.have.property('foo');
});
```

I got this assertion error:

```
AssertionError: expected {} to have a property 'foo'
```

I tried it with different use cases and assertions, but it's always the same, what comes out from `expect(promise)` is always an empty object.

Any idea why?

I use

```
"chai-as-promised": "6.0.0",
"chai": "^3.5.0",
"dirty-chai": "^1.2.2",
"mocha": "3.2.0",
"sinon": "^1.17.3",
"sinon-chai": "^2.8.0"
```

Comment: can you add how you imported your chai libs? should have something like 
`var chai = require("chai");
var chaiAsPromised = require("chai-as-promised");
 
chai.use(chaiAsPromised);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should work, as @LostJon mentioned you did not show how you imported chai libraries.
e.g.

```
let chai = require("chai");
let chaiAsPromised = require("chai-as-promised");

chai.use(chaiAsPromised);
let expect = chai.expect;

describe('chai as promise', () => {
    it('some async test', () => {        

        return expect(Promise.resolve({foo:'bar'})).to.eventually.have.property("foo");

    });
});
```

The example works with following:

```
"dependencies": {
    "chai": "^3.5.0",
    "chai-as-promised": "^6.0.0",
    "mocha": "^3.2.0"
  }
```

Comment: I updated my code, but this helped me find out what's going on. If I remove ```chai.use(dirtyChai);```, it works. so I guess dirtyChai cannot play together with chaiAsPromised. thanks

Comment: if I put ```chai.use(chaiAsPromised);``` before  ```chai.use(dirtyChai);``` then it works